# Android NV21 to grayscale print

Tags: android, grayscale, yuv

I have succeeded from onPreviewFrame (byte [] data, camera camera) {...}
Will NV21 extract Y for the gray value, but I want to print the gray value, gray value should be 0 ~ 255 But according to the black area should be 0 but printed out -16777216, how can I see 0 ~ 255
PS.I know that ARGB_8888 is 32 bits, so to extract A black area if 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

```
public Bitmap applyGrayScale( byte [] data, int width, int height) {
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    int p;
    int size = width*height;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        p = data[i] & 0xFF;
        pixels[i] = 0xff000000 | p<<16 | p<<8 | p;
        Log.d("pixels=", String.valueOf(pixels[i]));
    }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlcbj.png)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, all you need to do, is print `p` instead of `pixels[i]`.

Loop example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    p = data[i] & 0xFF;
    Log.d("pixels=", String.valueOf(p));       
}
```

`-16777216` is printed out in `ARGB_8888` format.
`-16777216` is the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation of `0xFF000000`.
The higher byte, equals `0xFF` is the alpha channel (opaque pixel - without transparency).
All three color channels are zeros.

The alpha channel is the reason why black is **not** `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`.
in `ARGB_8888` format, opaque black is: `11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000`.

For gray pixels three color channels have the same value: R = G = B.
Your code: `pixels[i] = 0xff000000 | p<<16 | p<<8 | p;` duplicates value of `p` to R, G and B, and set alpha channel to `0xFF` (255 in decimal).
See [ARGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) format for details.

So you can just print the value of `p`.